# Override an inherited class attribute in a subclass

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

There's a fine [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840196/c-sharp-override-an-attribute-in-a-subclass) on overriding inherited attributes of properties.

Suppose an attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true)]
public class MyAttributeAttribute : Attribute

//...

public class ParentClass
{
    [MyAttribute]
    public String MyString;
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    new public String MyString; //Doesn't have MyAttribute
}
```

But what if `MyAttribute` is set to a class?

```
[MyAttribute]
public class ParentClass

public class ChildClass; //Don't want MyAttribute
```

**Is there a way to make ChildClass not inherit the attribute?**

---

Context: Purely theoretical. I want to make an attribute inheritable and want to know, if the case happens some day, if I can override it.

Comment: Well, your first example is declaring a new member altogether that has _no relation_ to `ParentClass.MyString`; there is no overriding and naturally attributes wouldn't be shared. I know with reflection, you can get attributes either declared specifically to the target type _or_ flattened to include all attributes from any inherited classes.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair You are right. My wording is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could copy the [BrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx) approach mentioned in one of the answers to the question you reference. You can make a constructor with a boolean that when set to `false` will denote that the attribute, although present, should not be handled. You can also add a parameterless constructor that set the property to `true`. This is the one that you will use most often unless you decide to override the attribute inherited from a base class.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true)]
public class MyAttributeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool Enabled { get; private set; }

    public MyAttributeAttribute()
        :this(true)
    {
    }

    public MyAttributeAttribute(bool enabled)
    {
        Enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

Then when you reflect on your types and look for the attribute, you can check on the `Enabled` property and only if it is true you actually use it.

Your example class hierarchy will then be:

```
[MyAttribute]
public class ParentClass
[MyAttribute(false)]    
public class ChildClass; //Don't want MyAttribute
```

Comment: +1 It's an interesting solution, but it requires more work by whatever consumes the class and applies reflection to it. If there was a way to simply *rip* the attribute out or mask it...

Comment: @MPelletier Of course, this is a tradeoff. If you could isolate the reflection in a dedicated class or even better in a base class you would only have to do this once though. Another approach would be to create another attribute that specifies the opposite. Like the NonSerializedAttribute that informs the serializers that a specific field of a serializable class should not be serialized. This approach also needs extra work though.