# How to override inheritable attribute?

Tags: c#, inheritance, attributes, overriding

How can I override an inheritable attribute?

E.g. (using MSDN names for samples):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true)]  
class Attr1 : Attribute { ... }  

class BClass
{ 
    [Attr1( x )]  
    int i;
}  

class DClass1 : BClass
{ 
    // Will use Attr1(x) by inheritance and that's ok.
    override int i;
}   

class DClass2 : BClass
{ 
    // This will not work, will use Attr1(x) instead of Attr1(y) - NOK!
    [Attr1( y )]
    override int i;
}
```

Thank you!

EDIT: it seems that this appears to be the same problem than [C# Override an attribute in a subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840196/c-sharp-override-an-attribute-in-a-subclass) but using the **new** instead of **override** doesn't appear to solve my problem. Moreover, that question issues the **removal** of attributes, while my question addresses the **override** of existing attributes. Maybe it's different in some way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Override an attribute in a subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840196/c-sharp-override-an-attribute-in-a-subclass)

Comment: I try it and it works as expected. I don't see any problem here.

Comment: @Adam, tried that (using new instead of override) with same results.

Comment: @Niyoko Yuliawan, it's not really working with me. Not sure what is happening. I will continue trying, then post what the problem really was (probably nothing to do with overriding inheritable attributes...)

Comment: Can you include the code of how you're detecting the attribute? That could be where you and @NiyokoYuliawan are differing in what you find.

Comment: Well, what a shame. After intensive debugging, I've found that my base class was in fact being used instead of the derived class. Not relevant to explain here what was causing that (it's code in a complex ASP.NET MVC project with lots of layers developed by different people and sometimes it's not easy to spot how certain magic happens). I'm still struggling to make it work (as it is still not using the derived class, I can't assure it works in fact). What should I do with this post, now? :) I'll wait until the code is working, then I'll update the post to confirm it was a mistake (or not).

Comment: @RuiMiguelPinheiro So was it a mistake?

Comment: Wow, almost 2 years passed and I completly forgot this post. Not sure now how I fixed it (dozens of projects and millions of code lines after...) but after reading what I wrote here, it seems that yes, some misunderstanding of the code base at the time lead to this post and somehow I managed to fix it. Unfortunately I don't remember what exactly I did, as I changed the code to remove the specific parts and now I don't remember which one of the projects I was working at that time caused this issue.